# Extract last section of string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
[numbers]firstword[numbers]mytargetstring
```

I would like to know how is it possible to extract "targetstring" taking account the following :

a.) Numbers are numerical digits for example, my complete string with numbers:

```
12firstword21mytargetstring
```

b.) Numbers can be any digits, for example above are two digits each, but it can be any number of digits like this:

```
123firstword21567mytargetstring
```

Regardless of the number of digits, I am only interested in extracting "mytargetstring".

By the way "firstword" is fixed and will not change with any combination.

I am not very good in Regex so I appreciate someone with strong background can suggest how to do this using PHP. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can `mytargetstring` contain digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it (or should do)

```
$input = '12firstword21mytargetstring';

preg_match('/\d+\w+\d+(\w+)$/', $input, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // mytargetstring
```

It breaks down as

```
\d+\w+\d+(\w+)$
```

`\d+` - One or more numbers

`\w+` - followed by 1 or more word characters

`\d+` - followed by 1 or more numbers

`(\w+)$` - followed by 1 or more word characters that end the string.  The brackets mark this as a group you want to extract

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match("/[0-9]+[a-z]+[0-9]+([a-z]+)/i", $your_string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match) and [pattern syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

```
$string ='2firstword21mytargetstring';
if (preg_match ('/\d(\D*)$/', $string, $match)){
//                       ^ -- end of string
//                     ^   -- 0 or more
//                   ^^    -- any non digit character
//                ^^       -- any digit character                      
    var_dump($match[1]);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like,

```
print_r(preg_split('/\d+/i', "12firstword21mytargetstring"));
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Final string is: '.end(preg_split('/\d+/i', "12firstword21mytargetstring"));
```

Tested on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: be carefull when using functions manipulating with arrays like end, reset, etc..

This array is passed by reference because it is modified by the function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array because only actual variables may be passed by reference.

this code will result in Strict notification as of php 5.4

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for that:

```
for ($i=strlen($string)-1; $i; $i--) {
   if (is_numeric($string[$i])) break; 
}

$extracted_string = substr($string, $i+1);
```

Above it's probably the faster implementation you can get, certainly faster than using regex, which you don't need for this simple case.

See the [**working demo**](http://codepad.org/JbBlfmYT)

Answer (score 0):

your simple solution is here :-

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[\d,]+/", "hypertext123language2434programming");
echo($keywords[2]);
```